# How to use font glyphs on windows 8 tile?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, live-tile

I'm trying to figure out how to use a font glyph like the check box and check used in the windows 8 tile example from this page: [The tile template catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761491.aspx) under the "Task lists" example at the bottom.

I couldn't find much on how to get this to work because it appears there is a limitation on setting the font type in a tile.

On the [Segoe UI Symbol icon list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx) page, it says, "If you are working with tiles, you can't use these glyphs because you can't specify the tile font and PUA glyphs are not available via font-fallback.".

But I'm just wondering why there would be an example on the tile template catalog page with a font glyph?

Is there any way to set the font type inside of the tile xml? Or what are some alternatives that might get the same result?

[image: App tile with glyph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of Unicode symbol glyphs outside of the private-use area that fallback properly.  You find them with the charmap.exe applet in Windows for example.  Like ✓ and ☐ (U+2713 and U+2610)